# How to prompt user to open link with vlc

Tags: javascript, web, vlc

Currently on my website I ask the user to open a link in [VLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player), they do this by opening the VLC app navigating to network stream and pasting a link. Can I automate this so they click a button and get prompted to open a network stream in VLC?

Comment: https://github.com/stefansundin/vlc-protocol